# How do I redirect an anonymous user to custom page instead of the login page if they do not have access to a URL?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-security, symfony5

I created a login form for my Symfony 5 project.

I want redirect anonymous user to custom page (not the login page) when the user does not have access to my admin panel.

The application controller:

```
// TestController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/panel", name="test")
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
     */
    public function index()
    {

        return $this->render('test/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'TestController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my configuration settings:

```
# security.yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Admin:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        admin:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Admin
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin/

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
```

My application authenticator:

```
// AdminLoginFormAuthenticator.php 
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\Admin;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AdminLoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'app_admin' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['username']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Admin::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('...!');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('homepage'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_admin');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AdminLoginFormAuthenticator` extends on `AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator`, which includes the following:

```php
   /**
     * Override to control what happens when the user hits a secure page
     * but isn't logged in yet.
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $url = $this->getLoginUrl();

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
```

Reading this, what you need to do is obvious.

Just create your own `start()` method to control what happens (e.g. where are they redirected) if they do not have access.

```php
namespace App\Security;

class AdminLoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
// the rest of your class

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $url = 'https:://example.com/whateverurlyouwanttoredirectto';

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can't find start() method. I edit my question.

Comment: There is no `start()` method. You have to create it yourself. It exists on the class you are extending.

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Comment: Er... there is a syntax error in your file. Your PHP editor is probably telling you where it is.